# What counts as a service request in ArcGIS for Server 10.3.1?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, request

We've just updated our services to two new servers (Windows 2012) running ArcGIS for Server 10.3.1.

I'm trying to setup some statistics to monitor the usage on our new services, however I am having trouble finding any information in regards to defining what a "request" is.

I just finished publishing the last service, the environment has only been live for about 4 hours and it says there are already some folders with nearly 900 service requests.
If this number is accurate, great! I'm glad people are already using our services; though hard to believe...

So my main question here:
What signifies a service request?
Every time an image service is brought into arcmap? (this is hard to believe 900 people hit the same service within the last hour and a half)
Every time they zoom in or pan? (this is more believable if someone is panning around a lot and zooming on a single service)

Please help me better understand what these statistics are truly reporting!

[image]

Comment: A "request" is just that, an HTTP or HTTPS request against the REST API.  Some requests are "info" listings, but most requests are "make an image with these layers over this extent".

Comment: @Vince  So each request could mean simply each time a user changes their extent view of that service?

Comment: It depends on the client, and how it's pulling pages -- AJAX clients might pull multiple tiles to fill a single canvas.

Comment: Do you have any authentication configured, as this will also add HTTP requests.